# Do I have to use load_plugin_textdomain() or is there any default folder for languages?

Tags: localization

When I develop a plugin, do I always have to use:

```
load_plugin_textdomain('whatever', '', 'whatever/languages');
```

Or is there any setup, so that I put my translations into a specific folder with a specific name and they get loaded by default with the domain being the plugin slug?

Reason is, I don't like to use that second deprecated paramenter. I prefer to omit the whole call to the function if a default setup exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but it is not useful if you plan to bundle your language files with your plugin:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_plugin_textdomain/

> If the path is not given then it will be the root of the plugin directory.

So it will look in `wp-content/plugins`
The third parameter is only used if you want to use a subfolder.

Likewise, if a file exists at `wp-content/languages/plugins/` that matches your text domain and locale then it will be loaded.

---

**Although, you can just pass `false` as the second parameter, the only reason it's throwing deprecation warnings is because you've passed `''`.**

So pass `false` for the second parameter, and use the 3rd parameter. The two parameters behave differently so changing the second parameters behaviour would have been a break in backwards compatibility. So a 3rd parameter was added and the second was deprecated. This doesn't mean you need to avoid the function, just pass `false` **( passing `false` is not deprecated )**.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Could not be a better answer. I assume WordPress is not removing that deprecated parameter because it would break other plugins calling it with three paramenters. So, I'll be forced to use it if I want to bundle languages.

Comment: indeed, backwards compatibility is the issue, it's deprecated in the sense that you shouldn't rely on it, not that you should only pass a single parameter. In this case the 3rd parameter replaced the 2nd parameters functionality, because it behaves differently. I would not be concerned by passing `false` for the second parameter